# Does System.Drawing.Bitmap disposes data in it's destructor?

Tags: c#, .net, bitmap, dispose

I'm using .net Bitmap in many projects without disposing it's data explicitly with Dispose() and leave the data disposal to Bitmap's destructor.

Is my thinking true and Bitmap's destructor disposes the data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it will release the native GDI+ image. But it's still better to dispose it manually if you can, because there is no telling when the GC will collect and finalize the object. And if you somehow kept a reference to the `Bitmap`, the GC won't collect it at all, so the native image won't be released...

Comment: Avoid talking about HBITMAP, it is nothing like that.  Users will draw too many wrong conclusions from that, like using the wrong tools to try to diagnose leaks.  If you have to name it then say `GpImage*`.

Comment: @HansPassant, well, it seems *I* have already drawn the wrong conclusions then ;). Isn't the `Bitmap` class a wrapper around a HBITMAP handle? My knowledge of Win32 and GDI is limited, and I never heard about `GpImage`...

Comment: No, it is a wrapper for GDI+, not GDI.  A very different api that removes many of the legacy 24bpp GDI restrictions.  The underlying GpImage* *can* be converted to a legacy HBITMAP but that requires a conversion, Bitmap.GetHbitmap().

Comment: @HansPassant, thanks for the clarification; I reworded my answer.